# Find the characteristic function

Tags: probability

Suppose $X_1,X_2,…$ are independent each with uniform distribution $U(-1,1)$ and $N$ has a Poisson distribution (n) and is independent of $X_1, X_2,...$. $$$$ Find characteristic function of $\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N+1}X_i}{\sqrt{n}}$

$\varphi_{X_k} (t)=E(e^{itX_k})=...=\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2it}\\$
$\varphi(t)=E(e^{it\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N+1} X_i}{\sqrt{n}}})=E(E(e^{it\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i}{\sqrt{n}}}|P(N=n-1))=E(E(e^{it\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{\sqrt{n}}}))\\$
$E(e^{it\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{\sqrt{n}}})=E  (e^{it\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i})\cdot e^{\frac{it}{\sqrt{n}}} =E(e^{ itX_1}\cdot \cdot \cdot e^{itX_n})\cdot e^{\frac{it}{\sqrt{n}}} =E (e^{itX_1})^n\cdot  e^{\frac{it}{\sqrt{n}}}\\$$$$$
Am I doing it right? And if yes how do I continue?

---

Comment: Is $n$ the Poisson parameter or a particular value of $N$ on which you have conditioned?

Comment: It's Poisson parameter

Comment: What is $N_n$ supposed to mean? You have only defined a single random variable $N$, not a collection indexed (presumably) on the positive integers...

Comment: Sorry, $N$ was supposed to be $N_n$ not just $N$. I will corect it.